# How to remove disabled attribute and focus input Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, angular5

I am a bit confused trying to focus input that was disabled. I have input that is disabled at start. And after clicking a button i want remove disabled attr and focus this input.

I removed attribute from the input before focus `this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'disabled');`
and then tried to focus input `this.input.nativeElement.focus();` .

Where `this.input` is `@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;`
Disabled attribute disappears, but input is not focused. Here is [jsfidle](http://plnkr.co/edit/l1iL0WdPqyRWdnRmP5GQ?p=preview) 
I also tried bind to `[attr.disabled]` , but it didn't help.

What is the best solution for dynamic focus on the element and manipulating DOM's attributes in Angular? Btw i am using the latest Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elRef` is your host element that doesn't have `disabled` attribute

```
this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'disabled');
                                   ^^^^^
                             seems input should be here
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9qzqMbTWspx9hYvakW75?p=preview)**

### Update

> Why input is not focused in this case? I toggled isDisabled - so
>   disabled attr should be setted to null, am i wrong? An then we should be able to focus on input

That's because how angular change detection mechanism works.

It will be setted to `null` but **only after next VM turn when there are no microtasks**. Angular uses zone.js to run change detection.

```
this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled; // 1) you only change property
this.input.nativeElement.focus();  // 2) you executed focus(input is still disabled)
....
....
AppRef
  zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subcribe(() => run change detection) // 3) your template is updated
```

You have several options to overcome this problem:

1) Using `Renderer2` API as shown at the beginning of the answer

2) Subscribe to `onMicrotaskEmpty` event  [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/LG9keEWM6MmV2YXIIK1b?p=preview)

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators/take';

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

focus() {
  this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;

  this.zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.pipe(
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus();
  });
}
```

In this case angular app **won't call addition change detection cycle**.

3) Using `setTimeout` as was suggested in another answer.

Your angular application **will additionally check full component tree**.

4) Using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` method was suggested in comments of another answer.

```
this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled; 
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
this.input.nativeElement.focus();
```

**Additional check only this component and its children**

Comment: Thank you. It works. I have one more question. Why this code doesn't work? It removes `disabled` attr from DOM, but input is still not focused
`focus() {
   this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
   this.input.nativeElement.focus();
  }`
It seems like template updates after `this.input.nativeElement.focus();` called

Comment: `Why this code doesn't work?` which code? Angular updates template after you call focus method

Comment: Sorry, i mean this [jsfidle](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4gqG1gC12Y4CrLoG0Tn?p=preview) . Why input is not focused in this case? I toggled `isDisabled` - so `disabled` attr should be setted to `null`, am i wrong? An then we should be able to focus on `input`

Comment: Great updated answer. What about performance when using Renderer2? Is it the best way or not?

Comment: I don't see any problem with performance when using Renderer.

Comment: Thanks you for great and full answer. Amazing. I have new problem related to my question and I don't want to create open a new question.Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mkDYE97LLJioQoB7rKTY?p=preview).
I need disabled input that will be enabled and focused when we click on button. And disabled when we click anywhere outside input.
I found the solution with `e.stopPropagation()`, but it doesn't work when we have multiple inputs at the same time.If we have active input and click ob the button of the second input-first should be disabled. Is there better solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Amazing! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for the renderer at all, all you need is to wait one tick in so the view will be updated, therefore the nativeElement is no more disabled and can be focused:

```
focus() {
   this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.input.nativeElement.focus();
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works. But i am not really like setTimeout. I have to use it multiple times in several methods, because i need to handle `(blur)` event also.

Comment: You may try calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after toggling `this.isDisabled`, to force the DOM to update, instead of using `setTimeout`.

Comment: calling the ChangeDetector might work, at least it's worth a try